# Android - Sub classing ImageView - Error inflating class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

So I know that "Error inflating class" usually is because of a missing or malformed constructor... But I let eclipse generate them and they look similar to other examples I've seen. The error points to my XML file where I'm trying to add the custom class to my layout.

I'd assume I have to declare the extended ImageView some how but I'm at a loss for how to do so. Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Error

```
06-27 09:12:18.655: D/AndroidRuntime(1487): Shutting down VM
06-27 09:12:18.655: W/dalvikvm(1487): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
06-27 09:12:18.675: I/dalvikvm(1487): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-27 09:12:18.715: I/dalvikvm(1487): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mytheral.android.AnimationTimer/com.mytheral.android.AnimationTimer.AnimationTimerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class AnimationImageView
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class AnimationImageView
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.mytheral.android.AnimationTimer.AnimationTimerActivity.onCreate(AnimationTimerActivity.java:15)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     ... 11 more
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.AnimationImageView
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
06-27 09:12:18.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     ... 21 more
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <AnimationImageView
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AnimationTimerActivity

```
package com.mytheral.android.AnimationTimer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class AnimationTimerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final String TAG = "AnimationTimer";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");
        AnimationImageView image= (AnimationImageView) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        image.StartAnimation();
    }
}
```

AnimationImageView

```
package com.mytheral.android.AnimationTimer;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimationImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final String TAG = "AnimationImageView";

    private Timer imgTimer;
    private int currentFrame = 0;
    private int maxFrame = 269; //Testing Value
    private String fileName = "green_flag_"; //Testing Value

    public int getCurrentFrame() {
        return currentFrame;
    }

    public void setCurrentFrame(int currentFrame) {
        this.currentFrame = currentFrame;
    }

    public int getMaxFrame() {
        return maxFrame;
    }

    public void setMaxFrame(int maxFrame) {
        this.maxFrame = maxFrame;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public AnimationImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public AnimationImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AnimationImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void StartAnimation() {

        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");

        currentFrame = 0;
        maxFrame = 269;
        imgTimer = new Timer();

        try {
            imgTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    imgUpdateHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                }}, 0, 67);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Handler imgUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.v(TAG, "imgUpdateHandler: currentFrame: " + currentFrame);

            Uri imgUri;

            if (currentFrame <= maxFrame) 
            {
                int i = currentFrame;

                imgUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mytheral.android.AnimationTimer/drawable/" + fileName + String.format("%04d", i));

                //Uncomment if images don't cycle... Prior Android work around
                //image.setImageURI(null);

                try {
                    setImageURI(imgUri);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                currentFrame++;
            }

            if (currentFrame > maxFrame) 
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "imgUpdateHandler: stopAnimation");

                imgTimer.cancel();
                imgTimer.purge();
            }
        }       
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of this use

```
<AnimationImageView
```

use

```
<com.mytheral.android.AnimationTimer.AnimationImageView
     android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

or

```
<view class="com.mytheral.android.AnimationTimer.AnimationImageView"
         android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

/>